# Geometric interpretation of the difference between the means (ANOVA)

Tags: regression, anova, group-differences, multivariate-regression, geometry

First of all, a disclosure: I'm a medical doctor trying to understand statistics for research. Coming from a non-mathematical background I can do many mistakes.  I've read some traditional books of statistic but I like especially the "geometric" (or subject or column space) interpretation of the general linear model. It makes things much more intuitive. Relative to this approach my only problem is relative to the use of dummy vectors in ANOVA and, in general, the use of vectors to represents the difference between the means.

In the book "the geometry of multivariate statistic" it's written:

[image]

At the risk to seems stupid, I'm asking where are the means here?!

To make the question much clearer takes the traditional geometric (with only one X to makes things as simple as possible) representation of the regression:

[image]

In the particular case of difference between the mean the Y is regressed in the dummy vector (with different notations from another paper):
[image]

It's also explained that the lengths of these vectors have clear algebraic counterparts.

[image]

The lengths of the vectors are then:

[image]

The geometric meaning of SS-Tot is clear. The length (or the norm) of a vector is

[image]

But here we are working with centered data so that our *u* are already the deviation of any single values from the grand mean. Since we are interested in squared length what we obtain from simple geometry is exactly the definition of SS-Tot. This is great!

But I can't move forward. For the "treatments vector" I can't understand how the "each group mean" pops out. **V** (in the notation of the paper) is the projection of **Y** on **X** (in the notation of the books). How can the projection of Y on the dummy vector **X** be equal to the sum of the squared deviations of each group mean from the grand mean? For the Error Vector, I have the same problem. How can it be "the sum of the squared deviations of each observation from its group mean.”?

In extreme summary, I understand the geometric point of view and the algebraic point of view but I miss how the two are related here.

I'm wasting lots of hours on this, so everyone how wants to help will have my eternal gratitude.